# File permissions for mounted Samba share (from raspberry pi) on ubuntu server

Tags: samba, file-permissions

I am struggling with file permissions on a mounted NAS on my ubuntu server (`20.04 LTS`).

The NAS drive is mounted using cifs and `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab:

//PiNAS/PiNASdrive /media/PiNAS cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/USERNAME/.secrets/.smbdPiNAScredentials,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

The permissions are:

```
stat /media/PiNAS/:

File: /media/PiNAS/
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1048576 directory
Device: 33h/51d Inode: 2           Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    xxxx)   Gid: ( 1000/    xxxx)
```

when I try to change the permissions with `sudo chmod -R 0770 /media/PiNAS` the file permissions are not changed.

This is an issue when I try to set up a NextCloud docker container, as the NextCloud webapp tells me during installation:

> 'Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be
> listed by other users.'

**Can I change the file permissions consistently?**
Or is this a docker issue and do I have to do something about the file permissions inside the docker container (there is a folder on the NAS drive that's mapped as a volume in the docker container)

### Setup on raspberry pi 4; the NAS device

For completeness, here is how the NAS device is set up:

I have a raspberry pi 4 with two USB drives attached. I have used `mdadm` to create a simple 'RAID1' array:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Feb 18 20:37:27 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1953381440 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953381440 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Jul 19 21:38:53 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : PiNAS:0  (local to host PiNAS)
              UUID : d0b5192e:3b2b1fd7:f43639bb:e041cac6
            Events : 51229

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

This drive is mounted using `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID="1655887b-96c2-40dd-80e2-87e2fdce83c6" /media/USB12 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

And then it is shared through samba

```
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf:

<snip>
[PiNASdrive]
path = /media/USB12
writeable=Yes
create mask=0770
directory mask=0770
public=no
```

Comment: IIRC mount points behave differently to other directories, in fact their permissions are not the same before/after something is mounted. Is that NextCloud documentation also about a cifs mount or does it assume the user will use a local directory?

Comment: I checked the NextCloud documentation, and they do have native support for samba shares. The point is, since it's in a docker container I believe it is seen as a local drive by NextCloud?

Comment: I will look like a normal folder but chmod works different for mount points, I guess the real permissions are managed at the server who shares the files, or at the client program that mounts the share, like mount.cifs or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it - a bit more proper reading of various documentations would have been enough.

As @golimar has pointed out, a mount, although looking like a directory, is not exactly the same, and therefor also can act differently.

[Here](https://sysadmins.tech/linux-and-cifs-files-permissions/) is explained that file permissions are created at mount for cifs mounts, and cannot be changed after anymore. Moreover, you can pass a `dir_mode` and a `file_mode` to the mount command to set the permissions.

I first made a new directory as a mount point at `~/smbshares/PiNAS`. Then, I changed the permissions of the folder using `sudo chmod -R 0770 ~/smbshares/PiNAS`; although I'm not 100% sure if this is necessary or even does something at all.

Now, I can mount. For me the line in `/etc/fstab` now looks like this:

```
//PiNAS/PiNASdrive /home/USERNAME/smbshares/PiNAS cifs vers=3.0,credentials=/home/USERNAME/.secrets/.smbdPiNAScredentials,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770 0 0
```

A quick `sudo mount -a` (re-)mounts all drives.